# связи между таблицами в базе банных, как сделать правильно?

Tags: база-данных

Здравствуйте, есть таблицы:

- `Users` (username, password)
- `Orders`
- `Products` (name, price, id)

Как расставить правильно связи между этими таблицами, и какие поля сделать в таблице `Orders`, должна ли эта таблица быть промежуточной?

Comment: Вы не обяснили значения таблиц, и что в них должно быть.

Comment: В Orders делаете userID и productID. Она у вас будет общей для заказов. Итого, в Orders будут orderID, userID и productID.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan как в интернет магазине, юзер создает заказ(может быть много), в заказе товары(может быть много) и я вот пытаюсь все эти связи в базе данных сделать.Извините, у меня плохо получается объяснять.

Comment: @TO220 это получается связь многие ко многим?

Comment: @user254236, да.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю можно сделать так:

**Table Users**

```
`id`  `old fields`
```

**Products**

```
`id`  `old fields`
```

**Orders**

```
`id`  `user_id`  `product_id` `old fields`
```

Вот пример заказа, `user` заказал 2 тавара:

```
`id`  `user_id`  `product_id` `old fields`
`1`   `1`        `1`          `old fields`
`1`   `1`        `2`          `old fields`
```

Интересно будут ли другие предложения?